# CapsPageMenu Hide NavigationBar on TableView Scroll from child UIViewController not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am using following library to create tabs in my app

https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu

Child UIViewControllers have tableview I want to hide NavigationBar from child view controller but it not working

I have tried following things

```
self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

Added above code child UIViewController viewWillAppear method and Passed NavigationController to child from parent and called above code but its not working.

Tried another method below added code on tableview scroll but its leaving some empty space at top 
below tabs

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {


    if(velocity.y>0) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions(), animations: {

            self.navigateCont.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)

        }, completion: nil)

    } else {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions(), animations: {
            self.navigateCont.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)


        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set child controller view frame using,

```
newVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(index), y: menuHeight, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
```

Instead,

```
newVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(index), y: menuHeight, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height-menuHeight)
```

Inside  func addPageAtIndex(_ index : Int) of **CAPSPageMenu class**